# Xamarin 'iOS Foundation NSDate to C# DateTime conversion' and vice versa not accounting for DayLight saving

Tags: c#, ios, datetime, xamarin, nsdate

I need to convert `Cocoa NSDate` to `C# DateTime` and vice versa.

I am using the following method to achieve this:

```
 public static DateTime NSDateToDateTime (Foundation.NSDate date)
 {
    DateTime reference = TimeZone.CurrentTimeZone.ToLocalTime (
        new DateTime (2001, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0));
   return reference.AddSeconds (date.SecondsSinceReferenceDate);
 }

 public static Foundation.NSDate DateTimeToNSDate (DateTime date)
 {
    DateTime reference = TimeZone.CurrentTimeZone.ToLocalTime (
        new DateTime (2001, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0));
    return Foundation.NSDate.FromTimeIntervalSinceReferenceDate (
        (date - reference).TotalSeconds);
 }
```

But it turns out, this way it is not accounting for Daylight Saving.

Eg. `DateTime` object in which the time was 5AM in DST returns `NSDate` with time 6AM.

Answer (score 12):

I'm pretty sure this is an outdated approach. You can cast a NSDate directly to a DateTime now.

```
 Foundation.NSDate nsDate = // someValue
 DateTime dateTime = (DateTime)nsDate;
```

Comment: Yup you can directly cast now, but I've found this gives me an incorrect local DateTime (!), perhaps because I'm in New Zealand (aka UTC+12). So YMMV... Instead I use 7vikram7's solution successfully.

Comment: @tiritea NSDates are generally in UTC, so casting converts it to a UTC DateTime object. (You can check this by inspecting the `dateTime.Kind` property).
To convert the DateTime object in the above example to your local time you can use: `var localDateTime = dateTime.ToLocalTime()`

Comment: Something to note: Both answers work but both throw an exception when trying to convert a NSDate which is outside the supported date range of DateTime (which is 01.01.0001 - 31.12.9999)

Answer (score 6):

Based on inputs from:
https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/27184/convert-nsdate-to-datetime

`Local Time` changes during `Daylight Saving`.
Hence, always convert to `UTC` to do the calculations, then convert to `Local time` if needed.

```
     public static DateTime NSDateToDateTime (Foundation.NSDate date)
     {
        DateTime reference = new DateTime(2001, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc);
        var utcDateTime = reference.AddSeconds(date.SecondsSinceReferenceDate);
        return utcDateTime.ToLocalTime();
     }

     public static Foundation.NSDate DateTimeToNSDate (DateTime date)
     {
        DateTime reference = new DateTime(2001, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc);
        var utcDateTime = date.ToUniversalTime();
        return Foundation.NSDate.FromTimeIntervalSinceReferenceDate((utcDateTime - reference).TotalSeconds);
     }
```

Comment: I think this is an outdated approach, please see my answer

Answer (score 0):

There is a [creepy bug](https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-macios/issues/6993) on direct casting to NSDate

My solution was:

```
    public static NSDate DateTimeToNSDate(this DateTime date)
    {
        var calendar = new NSCalendar(NSCalendarType.Gregorian);
        calendar.TimeZone = NSTimeZone.FromName("UTC");
        var components = new NSDateComponents { Day = date.Day, Month = date.Month, Year = date.Year, Hour = date.Hour,
            Minute = date.Minute, Second = date.Second, Nanosecond = date.Millisecond * 1000000 };
        var result = calendar.DateFromComponents(components);

        return result;
    }
```

I hope this helps